# KNN prediction with L1 (Manhattan distance)

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, knn

I can run a KNN classifier with the default classifier (L2 - Euclidean distance):

```
def L2(trainx, trainy, testx):

    from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
    # Create KNN Classifier
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)

    # Train the model using the training sets
    knn.fit(trainx, trainy)

    # Predict the response for test dataset
    y_pred = knn.predict(testx)
    return y_pred
```

However, I want to use L1 (Manhattan) distance as my distance function.

The following is invalid (even though I thought I was following the documentation):

```
def L1(trainx, trainy, testx):

    from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
    from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric
    dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('manhattan')
    # Create KNN Classifier
    knn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1, metric=dist)

    # Train the model using the training sets
    knn.fit(trainx, trainy)

    # Predict the response for test dataset
    y_pred = knn.predict(testx)
    return y_pred
```

There is no predict() for NearestNeighbors, and my use of metric=dist is also wrong.

I want\need to do a prediction using KNN with the Manhattan distance function.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metric has to be passed as a string.

```py
def L1(trainx, trainy, testx):

    from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
    # Create KNN Classifier
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1, metric='manhattan')

    # Train the model using the training sets
    knn.fit(trainx, trainy)

    # Predict the response for test dataset
    y_pred = knn.predict(testx)
    return y_pred
```